# Oracle query cast attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, string

I am trying to convert a decimal to text. Every time I try to cast, it converts the number this way:

```
number:   converted: 
---------------------
0.1234    .1234
```

I tried using TO_CHAR, but without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the second format parameter of TO_CHAR function.

Try something like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.1234, '00000000.00') FROM DUAL
```